# A problem about isomorphism in module theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

For a sequence of $R$-modules like this:$A \overset{f}{\rightarrow} B \overset{g}{\rightarrow}C$ such that $\mathrm{Im} f \subset\ker g$ and $B/\mathrm{Im}f \cong B/\ker g$.

Then $\mathrm{Im}f=\ker g$ ?

Comment: No, a counterexample can be obtained with a Prüfer group like in my answer to your previous question.

Comment: Standard counterexample for questions like this: $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $B= \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \cdots$, $\ker g = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus 0 \oplus 0 \oplus \cdots$, $\operatorname{im} f = \mathbb{Z} \oplus 0 \oplus 0 \oplus \cdots$